# Angular2: Define two Async routes on the same path conditionally/ alternatively

Tags: angular

I could use some help to use the AsyncRoute in the RouterConfig. I have two components, that I need to load and have on the same path.

I have to make some if else statement where I can control what component should be loaded.

**Code:**

```ts
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/', name: 'Bookings', component: BookingsComponent },
{ path: '/bookings', name: 'Bookings', component: BookingsComponent, useAsDefault: true },
new AsyncRoute({
   path: '/mian/:id/...',
   loader: () => this.getMainComponent(),
   name: 'Main' 
}),
{ path: '/main/:id/...', name: 'Main', component: MainComponent },
{ path: '/main/:id/passenger', name: 'Passenger', component: PassengerComponent },
{ path: '/main/:id/date', name: 'Date', component: DateComponent },
{ path: '/main/:id/vehicle', name: 'Vehicle', component: VehicleComponent },
{ path: '/main/:id/confirmation', name: 'Confirmation', component: ConfirmationComponent },
{ path: '/main', redirectTo: ["Bookings"] },
])

@Injectable()
export class AmendmentComponent { 

locale: string;

constructor() {

    this.locale = localStorage.getItem('locale'); 
}

getMainComponent() {

    if (this.locale == "de") {
        return MainTestComponent;
    }
    else {
        return MainComponent;
    }

}
}
```

**Components that I import:**

```ts
import { MainComponent } from '../amendmentMain/mainComponent';
import { MainTestComponent } from '../amendmentMain/mainTestComponent';
```

As you see, I implemented the new AsyncRoute in the routerConfig. The path is the '/main/:id/...'

If locale is equal to "de" , the MainTestComponent should be loaded, and else the MainComponent should be loaded.

What have I done wrong here?

**Update getting an error on system, typescript can't find it:**

```ts
setMainComponent() {

    if (this.locale == "de") {

        this.router.config([
            new AsyncRoute({
                path: '/main:id/...',
                loader: () => System.import(MainComponent).then(m => m.MainTestComponent),
                name: 'MainComponent'
            })
        ])
    }
    else {

    }

}
```

**pdate: added some of index.html file**

```ts
  <!-- base url -->
  <base href="/">

  <link href="/assets/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Include lock0 module -->
  <script src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-8.1.min.js"></script>  

  <script>
      System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true 
      });
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <app>
     Loading...
 </app>

 {% if (o.webpackConfig.metadata.ENV === 'development') { %}
 <!-- Webpack Dev Server reload -->
 <script src="http://{%= o.webpackConfig.metadata.host %}:{%=     o.webpackConfig.metadata.port %}/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
 {% } %}

  <!-- Webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin manually inject scripts -->
  {% for (var chunk in o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %}
  <script src="{%= o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %}"></script>
  {% } %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register different routes for the same path, dynamically like this

```ts
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/', name: 'Bookings', component: BookingsComponent },
{ path: '/bookings', name: 'Bookings', component: BookingsComponent, useAsDefault: true },
{ path: '/main/:id/passenger', name: 'Passenger', component: PassengerComponent },
{ path: '/main/:id/date', name: 'Date', component: DateComponent },
{ path: '/main/:id/vehicle', name: 'Vehicle', component: VehicleComponent },
{ path: '/main/:id/confirmation', name: 'Confirmation', component: ConfirmationComponent },
{ path: '/main', redirectTo: ["Bookings"] },
])

@Injectable()
export class AmendmentComponent { 

locale: string;

constructor(public router:Router) {

    this.locale = localStorage.getItem('locale');
    this.setMainComponent();
}

setMainComponent() {

    if (this.locale == "de") {
       this.router.config([ 
           new AsyncRoute({path: '/main/:id/...', 
           loader: () => System.import('app/path/to/MainTestComponent').then(m => m.MainTestComponent), name: 'MainComponent'}];
    }
    else {
        this.router.config([ 
           new AsyncRoute({path: '/main/:id/...', 
           loader: () => System.import('app/path/to/MainComponent').then(m => m.MainComponent), name: 'MainComponent'}];
    }

  }
}
```

**Without Async Routes:**

```ts
   if (this.locale == "de") {
       this.router.config([ 
           { path: '/main/:id/...', name: 'MainComponent', component: MainTestComponent}];
    }
    else {
        this.router.config([ 
           { path: '/main/:id/...', name: 'MainComponent', component: MainComponent}]);
    }
```

Comment: What do you have to import, so the System.import works?

Comment: `System` is available globally (no need to import) if you are using `SystemJS` in your angular app, which is default , unless you have changed it otherwise. Do you get any error ?

Comment: Yep i get an error.. it tells me cannot find name System., have added the code.

Comment: does your `index.html` contain something like `System.config({` ?

Comment: Nope.. maybe is that the case :)

Comment: Maybe. Now It's getting out my knowledge, because I've only worked with `SystemJS` . Maybe someone else can help, or you may set up a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) then I can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Hmm ye.. i guess I'm missing something.. Have added some of my index.html file, also have added the Sytem.config, i found in google, but did not help :(

Comment: It seems that you do have `System.config({` in your html.[See this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) angular quickstart guide and match your configuration to find out what is missing. It's getting a little exhausting for me. :(

Comment: Thanks for your time.. , I'm using without async for now, but still need to do it right, so I'm going to read something about that System.JS which is some how not loaded?