# angular2 － dynamic url for component(like: /heroes or /heroes/:id all for HeroComponent)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/heroes(/:id)?', name: 'Heroes', component: HeroComponent}
])

ngOnInit() {
  let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
  if (id) {
    this._service.findById(id).then(hero => this.hero = hero);
  } else {
    this._service.findBy(null).then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes)
  }
}
```

when it has id,`findById(id)` other `findBy(model)`,because my list view and detail view all in one page,and i want write code in one `.ts` file, how to resolve?

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/heroes', name: 'Heroes', component: HeroComponent}
])
```

get url is `/heroes?id=11`,not REST,and config two route is badly

Comment: can't figure out the problem, can you elaborate ?

Comment: one route match two path,like:  `/heroes` `/heroes/1`  match herocomponent,    config  `/heroes(/:id)?`  id is not require param

Comment: [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134511/angular2-define-two-async-routes-on-the-same-path-conditionally-alternatively/36136642#36136642), is this what you needed ?

Comment: it's too many route config,I do not want